# There is any way to parse JSON on kernel modules?

Tags: json, linux, linux-kernel

I'm writing a kernel module that needs to parse json strings, and I was wondering if the linux kernel provides any API to do it, the way that I'm handling it now is writing a port of JSMN to the linux kernel but I think that this isn't an elegant way to do it, so there is any way more elegant to do it?

Comment: You probably do not want to handle arbitrarily nested structures in your kernel module, do you? If not, determine the structure of the inputs you want to allow and parse that directly.

Comment: I really need to handle these kind of objects. The kernel itself do this, on pmu-events, like [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/pmu-events/jsmn.c) . But this is not exported to be used on kernel modules

Comment: That is part of the userspace tool, not the kernel. You would need to at least eliminate recursion with local variables due to limited kernel thread stack space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux Kernel doesn't support JSON format natively.

This is an Open Source project that I'm developing for supporting JSON on Linux Kernel: https://github.com/emalele1688/JsonOnKernel

Library interface is documented into the `kjson.h` file. You can just link the library code into your project and start to use it. Here some example;

```
struct kjstring_t to_parse;
struct kjson_container *ctn;
struct kjson_object_t *obj;
char *str = "{\"accepted_1\": {\"codes\": []}, \"accepted_2\": [{\"codes\": []}, {\"enabled\": 1}]}"; // A simple JSON
kjstring_new_string_buffer(&to_parse, str, strlen(str));
ctn = kjson_parse(&to_parse); // This will start to parse the JSON
obj = kjson_lookup_object(ctn, "enabled");
int enabled = kjson_as_integer(obj); // is 1
```

You can find more example inside the repository.
Currently the library is under development by myself, and the repository is open for every pull request.